# How to run macros in excel irrespective of the file extension it is saved

Tags: excel, file-extension, vba

I would like to know,if the excel file with macro/vba code saved in any format (.xls, .xlsx ..etc), still the macros can run?

Or is there a way to run macros irrespective of the file extension format.

Comment: A workbook with macros saved has to be `.xlsm` (or sometimes `.xlsb`), what do you mean a macro saved in any format?  Edit: Are you asking how to run macros you have saved somewhere, on any file you open?

Comment: Actually i was trying to find out, is it possible to save an excel file in ".xlsx" format with macros. Also whether macros will be available after saving .xlsx format on re-opening the file?

Comment: It is a security feature that prevents an `.xlsx` from containing macros. This is by design. "Excel cannot open the file 'Book1.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file. "

Comment: @user2249207 - No and emphatically **No**. Are you not receiving the warning dialog I added to my response below when you try?

Comment: Save it as `.xlsm` or `xls` or move your macros to `PERSONAL.XLSB` and run it on any `Active-workbook or Sheet`

Comment: Or you can make an `add-in`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A workbook saved as an .xlsx **cannot** contain a VBA project.

[image]